# Powershell Excel Activate Cell like with double click and send Enter

Tags: excel, powershell

so i know this is a wierd on. i had this same issue a long time ago in Excel but i think with VBA...

so i put data from mails into Excel like this. (don't mind the format i'm german)

```
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow, 3) = $MItem.ReceivedTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

The Date is written in the Cell.
BUT it is shown on the left side of the cell. and i can't use VLOOKUP and stuff

if i double click into the cell and press Enter, the Date jumps to the right side and everything works...

Excel knows already that it is a Date. But the Cell must be "revalidated" through the activation.

i though i have to just

```
 $workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow, 3).Activate()
 $workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow, 3).DoubleClick()
```

or something like it but i can't even get into the cell.

i hope someone cann help me.
regards

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply sadly this dow not help. something i will add to the original post is that it shows as Date Format in Excel. so Excel knows already that it is a Date. But the Cell must be "revalidated" through the activation. i just don't know how to do this automaticaly. and i don't want to do it manual on over 900 Cells :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date in Excel is a formatted number, not a `String`. The format and the underlying value are separate.

Instead of writing a `String` version of the date, write the actual date and then apply number formatting:

```
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow, 3) = $MItem.ReceivedTime
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($LastRow, 3).NumberFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
```